# Finding whether all characters in a for loop match a requirement(s)

Tags: python

I have a list; `list_words_punc` which is a list of all the words in an `input()` using the `split()`. I then have another list; `list_words` which is a list of all the words in that same `input()` but without their punctuation (I.e **.,?!**). `sentence` is the `input()`. I want the program to check for all words in `list_words_punc` that every letter is a letter and it all gets appended to my new list `list_words`; any other punctuation is disbanded. The error I'm having is that if I use `for s in l: if s.isalpha()` and then append that to my new list, the list will be appending the letters as separate words instead of appending the same words from `sentence` just without punctuation. Is there any way to append the words?

```
list_words_punc=sentence.split()
list_words=[]
for l in list_words[]:
    for s in l:
        if s.isalpha():
```

Example just if I was unclear:

```
sentence="How, are you?"
list_words_punc=sentence.split()
list_words=[]
for l in list_words[]:
    for s in l:
        if s.isalpha():
```

I get:

```
["H","o","w"," ",...]
```

Answer (score 2):

###### You could use regex to achieve this

1. `re.findall()` returns all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.
2. `\w` represents a single word character
3. `\w+` means one or more of a word character

Hope you understood.

Example:

**Code**

```
import re
sentence="How, are you?"

list_words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
print(list_words)
```

**Output**

```
['How', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is appending at the end. The operation of appending always creates a new index and appends that value at that index. So, what you do is something like this.

```
sentence="How, are you?"
list_words_punc=sentence.split()
new_words=[]
index=0
for l in list_words_punc:
    word=''
    print(l)
    for s in l:
        if s.isalpha():
            word+=s
        else:
            new_words.append(word)
            word=''
    if word!='':
        new_words.append(word)
        word=''
print(new_words)
```

So, you don't append character by character, instead create and store in an index (it is inefficient), but it works and removes all the punctuation and the list new_words has the words without punctuation

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are iterating on list assigned none that is wrong itself
Now answering question you just need to append each character at the end of string.

```
sentence="How, are you?"
list_words_punc=sentence.split()
list_word=[]
for word in list_words_punc:
    s=""
    for c in word:
        if c.isalpha():s=s+c
    list_word.append(s)
print (list_word)
```